# CRUD with SQFlite in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

hello I have made an app that can write and delete files in SQFlite. But I need help with updating an existing entry. I will paste my code below.

For Create I used -
`db.insert('todo',{'id': newTodo.id,'description': newTodo.description,'isDone': newTodo.isDone == true ? 'true' : 'false',},);`

For Delete I used -
`final db = await _getDatabse(); await db.rawDelete('DELETE FROM todo WHERE id = ?',[deleatableTodo.id],);`

What shoudl I do to update a todo?

Comment: use `db.update()`

Comment: You should look at Drift for a full ORM-like solution.  It should save some boring coding hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  // Update an item by id
  static Future<int> updateItem(
      int id, String? descrption, String? isDone) async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();

    final data = {
      'description': descrption,
      'isDone': : newTodo.isDone == true ? 'true' : 'false'
    };

    final result =
        await db.update('items', data, where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
    return result;
  }
```

Make this function:

```
  // Update an existing journal
  Future<void> _updateItem(int id) async {
    await SQLHelper.updateItem(
        id, _titleController.text, _descriptionController.text);
    _refreshJournals(); // this is an select statement
  }
```

Then call it when you press the button:

```
if (id != null) {
   await _updateItem(id);
}
```

And here is a video if would like it as gives all operation but its in an Arabic language:

[Complete CRUD Operations with SQLite](https://youtu.be/REsXH5GtLeo)